# In Swift, can you find all types in a module that adhere to a specific protocol?

Tags: swift, reflection, mirror

In Swift 4, is it possible to find all types within the current module which adhere to a specific protocol?

For instance, say I've defined this protocol and these classes:

```
protocol Animal{}
protocol Vehicle{}
protocol Favorite{}

class Dog : Animal{
}

class Cat : Animal, Favorite{
}

class Car : Vehicle{
}

class Bicycle : Vehicle, Favorite{
}
```

I want to find all types that implement `Favorite`.  This can be easily done in C#, but I’m not sure if you can in Swift.

- Cat
- Bicycle

If it helps, I'm using Swift 4.

Comment: This will only work for @objc classes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't believe Swift currently has a 'native' (not dependant on the Objective-C runtime) API for doing this kind of reflection.

However, if you're on an Apple platform (and therefore have Obj-C interoperability), you could get a list of all *classes* registered with the Obj-C runtime, and then filter those that conform to a given protocol. This will work for Swift classes (even those that don't inherit from `NSObject`) because under the hood Swift classes are built on top of Obj-C classes (when there's Obj-C interop).

Because this will only work for classes (not structures or enumerations), you may want to restrict your protocol such that only classes can conform to it:

```
protocol Favorite : class {}
```

You can then do the following, using [`objc_copyClassList`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418762-objc_copyclasslist):

```
import Foundation

protocol Animal {}
protocol Vehicle {}
protocol Favorite : class {}

class Dog : Animal {}
class Cat : Animal, Favorite {}
class Car : Vehicle {}
class Bicycle : Vehicle, Favorite {}

/// Invokes a given closure with a buffer containing all metaclasses known to the Obj-C
/// runtime. The buffer is only valid for the duration of the closure call.
func withAllClasses<R>(
  _ body: (UnsafeBufferPointer<AnyClass>) throws -> R
) rethrows -> R {

  var count: UInt32 = 0
  let classListPtr = objc_copyClassList(&count)
  defer {
    free(UnsafeMutableRawPointer(classListPtr))
  }
  let classListBuffer = UnsafeBufferPointer(
    start: classListPtr, count: Int(count)
  )

  return try body(classListBuffer)
}
//                               .flatMap in Swift < 4.1
let classes = withAllClasses { $0.compactMap { $0 as? Favorite.Type } }
print(classes) // [Bicycle, Cat]
```

Here we're calling `compactMap(_:)` on the `UnsafeBufferPointer` to get back an array of metatypes that represent types conforming to `Favorite` (i.e those that can be cast to the existential metatype `Favorite.Type`).

Answer (score 0):

**No it is not possible to get names of classes inside a module.**

Answer (score -1):

You can count by your code, use extension protocol to count like below code :)

```
protocol Animal{}
protocol Vehicle{}
protocol Favorite{
  func countImplement()
}

var totalImplement = 0
extension Favorite {
  func updateTotalImplement(){
    totalImplement += 1
  }
}

class Dog : Animal{
}

class Cat : Animal, Favorite{
   func countImplement(){
    this.updateTotalImplement()
  }
}

class Car : Vehicle{
}

class Bicycle : Vehicle, Favorite{
   func countImplement(){
    this.updateTotalImplement()
  }
}
```

Comment: The issue is with this you have to know what the types are. Plus, you have to add things to those types, which is not possible in my case as I'm trying to discover existing classes, not author them. In short, I'm trying to write a function which discovers all types in a module that adhere to a protocol.  You simply define the type, implement the protocol, and it's automatically discovered.

Comment: Go with Hamish's answer :)