# Finding all types that conform to a protocol

Tags: swift

Let's say I have a protocol that many types conform to:

```
protocol Swizzled {
  static func swizzle()
}
```

Is there a way I could go about finding *every* type that conforms to this protocol?

Comment: You mean like search your code? Maybe write yourself better documentation?

Comment: No -- I mean, I want to get the `Type` of all structs/objects that conform to a protocol. I know this is possible with the Objective-C runtime for ObjC protocols, but is this possible for pure Swift protocols?

Comment: You can’t do it _in code_; there is no introspection for getting all possible types. And your code would never need this info. So I’m trying imagine what meaning your question can have. You made the types conform so what is there to know?

Comment: if you can create object `type(of:object)`

Comment: Well -- in this specific instance, it's a protocol that implies that the classes are swizzled. Ideally, I'd like to be able to identify each of these classes at launch time and replace the implementations of methods using the protocol's `swizzle` function such that I don't have to have a massive injection function that runs at application launch.

Comment: Well you can't in Swift, so bring on the massive injection function.

Comment: If it's classes you're looking for on an Apple platform, you can query the Obj-C runtime: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47788562/2976878

Comment: But @Hamish he specifically says "but is this possible for pure Swift protocols" and "all structs/objects that conform to a protocol".

Comment: @matt Sure, but he then said in a later comment "Ideally, I'd like to be able to identify each of these classes at launch time" :)

Comment: @Hamish Fair enough. But then this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a collection of objects then sure, you could filter it to only leave the objects that conform to your protocol.

If you mean scouring your app at runtime to find all types that are DEFINED that conform to your protocol, I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Late for the party, you may find this useful, but only for classes.  If you declare `init` in the protocol, you may be able to instanciate of those objects as well.

https://gist.github.com/codelynx/bb72bf0bed58a327ce1dbe6639d0369b